# cftextarea - regex - Microsoft text encoding issue

Tags: regex, coldfusion, cfform

I have a form with the below regex in, my issue is that when people paste in text from a word doc this symbol `'` won't pass through the regex, where as is will when typed in.

I added `/x27` which is what's allowing it to be typed into the formfield, and tried adding `/x91` and `/x92` also, to no avail.

Has anyone experience this issue before?

```
pattern="^([\w\s!@.,;:\*\%&"" \)\(\x2f \x5C\x27?-]){1,2050}$"
```

Symbol when typed (**Allowed**): `'`

Symbol when pasted (Not **Allowed**): `‘`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using characters instead of just pasting `'` and `‘` into the expression?

Comment: The problem is caused by having smart quotes being enabled in word.  Before deciding how to code for this, you must first decide what you want to do about it.  Maybe you want to allow them, maybe you want to convert them to straight quotes.

Comment: @BradleyMoore Hi Bradley, putting the character in itself has worked! The reason I wasn't before is that the hex value had to be used for the `'` character, as otherwise it breaks coldfusion's validation as it uses single quotes for the attributes of the form element! Thanks very much guys! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer from comments:**

Use the literal `‘` character instead of `\x27`

**Better answer:**

Ditch that validation - it's just getting in the way, and provides no security.

Ideally, ditch cfform entirely and if you actually need validation, use one of the tools listed at [cf411.com/form](http://cf411.com/form)